# Is it possible to use Sonar Web reporting tool stand alone?

Tags: web, sonarqube, reporting, web-frontend, sonarqube-web

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) is a tool use for code quality inspection, it is based on plugins. Sonar has built-in web reporting tool which shows analysis results on web page via different charts and UI controls.

My understanding is that: "Sonar provides different plugins for it's different functionalities, for example sonar-php  is a plugin that can be used for analyzing php code, once the code is analyzed it represent the results on web page by mentioning different stats and graphs/charts."

If the above understanding is correct, I assumed Sonar use some kind of web reporting plugin to show all cool graphs and controls to display analysis results that is independent of data source and only responsible of presenting the provided data.

Now, my question is , Suppose I do have some data source , Is it possible to customize and use only that web reporting tool of Sonar to display results on web page ? or it's not possible and I have wrong assumption?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to clarify what you find lacking or unsatisfactory about the UI and exactly what you mean when you say "use this reporting tool stand alone just as a web reporting user interface to show provided data" other than just... using the UI.

Comment: Hey,thanks for response,  I have updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarQube is a code quality management tool. There is no specific web reporting tool to display whatever data you want.

If you want to analyze code, you can create a plugin to inject issues on specific part of the code for example. You may be interested by the documentation « [Developing a Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+a+Plugin) »